# Show full details of 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, internal-server-error

How do I see the full error in a page which returns 500 internal error?

All I see is the error number and description -internal server error- with no exact details of the details of the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, though I would recommend setting up [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

It will log the exception with stack trace and provide a web interface to see it.

There are other loggers ([log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)) and you can write your own logging (`Exception.ToString()` will provide most of the needed information for tracking down a bug), but I find ELMAH to be easy to get going.

Comment: Any idea for Apache/PHP enviroment

Answer (score 1):

Check the error logs. Where they are located is dependent on your serer setup though.

Answer (score 1):

If the error is happening on your ASP.NET app, you can catch the error and email it to yourself.

You can catch the error in the Global.asax file...

```
    Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    sb.AppendFormat("Page Location: {0}", Context.Request.RawUrl)
    With Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException
        sb.AppendFormat("Message: {0}", .Message)
        sb.AppendFormat("Source: {0}", .Source)
        sb.AppendFormat("Method: {0}", .TargetSite)
        sb.AppendFormat("Stack Trace: {0}", .StackTrace)
    End With
    Dim ErrorMsg As String = sb.ToString()
    ' Post thee error to a logger...

End Sub
```

G.

Comment: I suggest you look at the result of `Exception.ToString()`. In contains all of the above that you are putting into the string builder.